# How to Unlock thousands of records as they are locked due to approval process

Tags: approval-process

Hi is there any way to fetch all the opportunity records which are in the locked state due to the approval process and as an administrator I want to unlock all the records at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a one-time activity you are trying to do, I would recommend you write a batch apex code and make use of the `Approval` Class methods mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm#apex_methods_system_approval). You can use the `isLocked` and `unlock` methods. Before you execute this code, check if you have enabled ***Enable record locking and unlocking*** in Apex under ***Settings > Process Automation > Process Automation Settings***.

Also refer [this](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm#rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks) for some more information.